# How to place a scrollbox within a div column?

Tags: html

I have an image within the content of my Div Column ID. This column is in the middle.

The image inside of the middle div column ID is a book. I would like a text box to be able to move to this middle div column ON TOP of the book image. I can not figure it out.

Here's the HTML code to my middle section.

```
    <div id="middle">
        <img src="http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/1369/bookbf.png"/>

</div>
```

Here's the CSS code to my middle section

```
div#middle {
    padding: 0px 30px 5px 160px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;}
```

If you still can not figure out what I am trying to achieve, just think about a text box being placed on the right page of that book, located within my div column.

I am a complete newb when it comes to css so please outline in layman's terms where I need to add what.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you put

```
background: url('http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/1369/bookbf.png');
```

in the css file. In this case, that `<img>` tag wouldn't be necessary anymore.

That way, the book image will become the background of the div, so the textbox will be automatically above it.

Maybe I didn't understand completely your question and the above code won't help you? Please add a comment in my answer, if that's the case.